# Query for recent images across multiple posts

Tags: images, widgets

I'm a bit fresh to wordpress theme development (and PHP in general), and I'm curious if there is a way to query XX number of recent images, likely spanning across multiple posts. Basically I want to create a widget that shows a 3x3 set of the most recent images used in posts.

Any thoughts on how one would accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_posts` or create a new `WP_Query` using the following args (or something similar).

```
<?php 
$args = array(
   'post_type'      => 'attachment', // attachment post type
   'post_status'    => 'inherit', // all attachments have this post status
   'post_mime_type' => 'image', // make sure you get images only
   'posts_per_page' => 5 // however many images you want
);
```

When looping through the images, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) or [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to grab the image HTML or image URL respectively.

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts($args); // args from above
foreach($attachments as $a)
{
   // replace `thumbnail` with an appropriate image size
   echo wp_get_attachment_image($a->ID, 'thumbnail');
}
```

You'll also want to read up the [widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) for creating widget.  The codex has a [basic example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget#Example). There's also quite a few tutorials out there, here's [one I wrote](http://pmg.co/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-widgets).

Comment: I don't know why I didn't know this. I had another query virtually identical elsewhere, but where I specified
"'post_parent' => $post->ID);" to filter it down to the given post